How to parse C++'s template syntax with the recursive-descent parser?
While writing a C++ parser for learning purposes, I had a question.
int a, b;
template <typename T> T Foo() {}
int main() {
    bool x = a < b;
    auto y = Foo<int>();
}

Here, < symbol in a < is less-than operator. But in Foo<, that means the start of template parameters. Both are essentially identifier, followed by the < symbol, in expression. Can the recursive-descent parser handle this situation? Or can only more powerful parsers like the LR parser handle this?

A recursive-descent parser should be able to handle this. You should be able to start with the rule that you are parsing a template, and if it fails, use backtracking to try a different rule. E.g. clang's Parser::ParseTemplateParameterList seems to do something similar ("If the parsing fails badly (i.e., closing bracket was left out), this will try to put the token stream in a reasonable position (closing a statement, etc.) and return false.").

There are genuinely ambiguous cases that can only be disambiguated by name lookup. (e.g. (A<B>::C))

Ah, so "trying" is always necessary? So far, parsing basic expressions and statements, I've never had to implement trying and handling failure. I could preview a single token and decide what to do.

C++ is tricky; don't use that for "learning purposes"...

C++ has, from memory, 53 shift/reduce conflicts. This is not going to be easy.

Recursive-descent parsers
are more powerful than LR parsers, not less.
A recursive-descent parser is usually written in a
Turing-complete
programming language (such as C++), while an
LR parser only has the
theoretical power of a
pushdown automaton.
Now, recursive-descent parsers also typically have a regular, top-down
structure similar to LL parsers,
and since LL is less powerful than LR, it's understandable to suspect
recursive-descent is also less powerful.  But, because it has access to
all of the features of a conventional programming language, a
recursive-descent parser can use very powerful lookahead techniques,
limited only by decidability, including arbitrary backtracking (which is
essentially using the parser as its own lookahead mechanism).
In any case, how does a typical recursive-descent parser handle the
C++ left-angle-bracket ambiguity?  First we have to know what we want to
accomplish, and for that, C++17 17.2 ([temp.names]) paragraph 3 says:

When a name is considered to be a template-name, and it is followed by
a <, the < is always taken as the delimiter of a
template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator.  [...]

So, in an expression context, if we see:
  identifier <

then we need to look up identifier to determine if it should be
"considered to be a template-name" (the rules for which are in paragraph
2 of the same section, and have some subtleties I'll omit), which is
principally determined by looking up the identifier in the
symbol table.  If it is
found to refer to a template, then we treat the < as starting a
template argument list, otherwise as the less-than operator.
A concrete example of the technique can be found in the Clang parser.
In
Parser::ParseUnqualifiedId,
we have:
  // unqualified-id:
  //   identifier
  //   template-id (when it hasn't already been annotated)
  if (Tok.is(tok::identifier)) {
  ParseIdentifier:
    // Consume the identifier.
    IdentifierInfo *Id = Tok.getIdentifierInfo();
    SourceLocation IdLoc = ConsumeToken();

    [...]

    // If the next token is a '<', we may have a template.
    TemplateTy Template;
    if (Tok.is(tok::less))
      return ParseUnqualifiedIdTemplateId(
          SS, ObjectType, ObjectHadErrors,
          TemplateKWLoc ? *TemplateKWLoc : SourceLocation(), Id, IdLoc,
          EnteringContext, Result, TemplateSpecified);

and then
ParseUnqualifiedIdTemplateId
contains code to check if the identifier is a template:
      TNK = Actions.isTemplateName(getCurScope(), SS,
                                   TemplateKWLoc.isValid(), Id,
                                   ObjectType, EnteringContext, Template,
                                   MemberOfUnknownSpecialization);

and, if TNK indicates a template was found, code that parses the
template argument list:
  // Parse the enclosed template argument list.
  SourceLocation LAngleLoc, RAngleLoc;
  TemplateArgList TemplateArgs;
  if (ParseTemplateIdAfterTemplateName(true, LAngleLoc, TemplateArgs, RAngleLoc,
                                       Template))
    return true;

Meanwhile, surrounding code I have not shown deals with the case where
the name is not considered to be a template name.  In that case, it sets
Result to just the identifier, then returns false.  That (perhaps
unexpectedly) means "successful parse", and bubbles up to
Parser::tryParseCXXIdExpression which processes the identifier alone,
leaving the < as the next token in the input token stream, where it
will eventually be treated as less-than.
There are other contexts in which a similar decision has to be made, and
other ambiguities that require more mechanism to handle (including the
right-angle-bracket ambiguity, which is its own can of worms), but this
code illustrates the basic idea: when faced with a difficult choice,
check the possibilities one by one, taking care to isolate any parser
state changes caused by speculative parsing that didn't work out.
But, having explained the basic idea, I should caution that parsing C++
is extremely difficult, far more difficult than any other language I'm
aware of.  If you're an experienced language implementor eager for a
"final boss" challenge that will take years if not decades to complete,
go for it.  But if you just want to learn the basics, I strongly
recommend picking a different language.

Just to clarify LL(k) where k is large (which you refer to here as recurisve decent) will be more powerful than LL(1) but the same argument can be made to LR(k)

@doron Both LL(k) and LR(k) have a fixed lookahead distance (the 'k'), which makes them theoretically less powerful than a Turing-complete language.  Recursive descent is not equivalent to LL(k) for any k.
